# qx.ui.embed.Html scale to content

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to have the container containing an html widget (qx.ui.embed.Html) scale to the proper size so it doesn't cut off some of the Html?

Here's a playground example:
http://tinyurl.com/a4twfdc

Notice how the Three and Four get cut off.

The only way I could fix this was to define a minHeight and minWidth for the container, but my html can vary in size, so I end up with a large blank area or not enough room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could think of a fix is to render the HTML prior into a helper div and take the offsetWidth / offsetHeight and apply it to the embed as well. That helper DIV could be out of the view port at e.g. -1000 / -1000 and you can set the HTML as innerHTML. Maybe that could solve your problem for the initial size. But as soon as the content of the embed changes dynamically, you have to redo the calculation if you can.